# concat empty / single item array

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I have this simple code :

```
for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    elements += myFunction(lines[i]);
}
```

Where `elements` is an empty array at the start and `myFunction()` is just a function that returns an array of strings.

The problem is that if `myFunction()` returns an array with a single string, the `+=` is interpreted as a string concat in place of an array concat.
At the end of the loop the result is just a long string and not an array.

I tried `push()`ing the values in place of concatenation, but this just gives me a two dimensional matrix with single item arrays.

How can I solve this typecasting problem ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Plz give some code , what have you tried and some example would be handful to help you.

Comment: Show some (minimal) sample input and what you want as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
 for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        elements [i] = myFunction(lines[i]);
    }
```

I suppose it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem. You just have to change lines[i] into lines[0]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Array `concat` function:

```
elements = elements.concat(myFunction(lines[i]));
```

Comment: actually concat returns an empty array

Comment: `[].concat(['some-string'])` equals `['some-string']`, which I'm pretty sure is the desired output you described. Are you assigning the result of `concat` (it doesn't modify the array, it returns a new one)?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want something like:

```
var arrs = [[0],[1,2],[3,4,5],[6]];
var result = [];

for (var i=0, iLen=arrs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  result = result.concat(arrs[i]);
}

alert(result); // 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Ah, you want to concatenate the results of a function. Same concept, see other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `myArray[myArray.length] = someValue;`

Comment: Actually, that would assign the item outside of the bounds. `myArray.length - 1` would be the index of the last element instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
let newArray = [].concat(singleElementOrArray)
```